# How to use AjaxForm Plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

trying to learn to use AJAX on a form (using the AJAXForm plugin) to then be processed with PHP and am having a lot of trouble.

Basically, I have a form with a bunch of fields that I want to passed through an AJAX call to some page that will process it. Here is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="aligned" class='add'>
 . . . . .yadda yadda yadda. . . .      
<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Add</button>                                                              
</form>
```

And at the bottom of the page, I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
    $('.add').ajaxForm(function() { 
        alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
    }); 

    $('.add').ajaxForm({
        url: this.href, type:'post', 
        data: this.serialize()+'&action=update',
        success: function(){alert('ok'+responseText.text);}, 
        error: function(){alert('ok'+responseText.text);} 
    });

});
```

The first ajaxForm function works on cue, so I must be doing something wrong with the way I'm doing the second one, even though I am trying to follow different examples I found online.

I don't have much going on in the PHP page--just a simple 'echo'.

(-Do I need to do something to set it to success/error (and because I'm not is why it's not doing anything)?
-Is my format wrong?
-Is responseText.text not the right way to get theecho'ed back information?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see error in your code,you need add responseText in signature of function

```
    success: function(responseText){alert('ok'+responseText.text);},

    error: function(responseText){alert('ok'+responseText.text);}
```

Comment: That was the issue (along with using responseText.text instead of 'responseText')--thank you!